# Angular 2 - What's the equivalent of routerLinkActive="active" inside a TypeScript (.ts) file?

Tags: css, angular, angular2-routing

I was using `routerLinkActive="active"` inside the html file with `routerLink=[myId]` to highlight the active anchor in a ul.

Example:

```
<a [routerLink]="[myId]" class="list-group-item clearfix" routerLinkActive="active">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{someName}}</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

But when I remove the `[routerlink]="[myId]"` and replace it with a click listener (that does some calculation and then redirects the route using `this.router.navigate(['/someURL', myId])` ) the `routerLinkActive="active"` no longer works/highlights.

Example:

```
<a (click)="onClick(myId)" class="list-group-item clearfix" routerLinkActive="active">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{someName}}</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

When inspecting the anchor elements using the `routerLink=[myId]`, the style is set to:

```
.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:focus, .list-group-item.active:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #337ab7;
}
```

Is it possible to set the active anchor style in the .ts file in the `onClick()` function? Or is there a simpler way around this?

Comment: You can use the code from the `RouterLinkActive` class and tailor it to your needs https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b141a227fb5f0c26d1fd94e6389b6d0665be4a63/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L84

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting a specific link in the navigation is a reflection of the **current state** of the app: link A is highlighted because the user is looking at page A.

You're asking how to highlight the link **as the result of a click**. This approach is less than ideal: you could end up highlighting the link **before** the new route/page is actually activated. Most importantly, if the user reloads the page or navigates to it directly because they bookmarked it, the link will NEVER be highlighted (because no one clicked it).

You need to find a way to highlight the link based on app state, NOT as the result of an action (the typical flow is: action => changes state => updates UI).

Maybe something like this:

```ts
@Component({
  template: `
    <a [class.active]="currentPath == 'home'">HomeComponent</a>
  `
})
export class HomeComponent {
  currentPath = '';
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // Retrieve current path.
    this.currentPath = snapshot.url.join('');
  }
}
```

The idea is to retrieve the current path and expose it to the template.

Like Günter suggested, you can probably find more robust code for testing the current path in `routerLinkActive`'s source code.